# How to do a "backwards" regular expression search and extract

Tags: php, regex, validation, url, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of URLs to parse in PHP, like this:

```
www.example.com/shopping
shopping.example.com
example.com/pages/shopping
```

for about 100 different pages (not just shopping - some are contact, some are directions, etc.).  I have a seed set of data, which tells me where to look for the page names, like this:

```
www.example.com/[pagename]
[pagename].example.com
example.com/users/[pagename]
```

My question is, how do I get the page name from a URL using the seed data to tell me where it is?

So if I use the URL `www.example.com/shopping` I want to compare it to `www.example.com/[pagename]`, and then just give me the page name of "shopping", pulled out from the string.

Comment: Regarding your example, you'll probably want to compare it to `www\.example\.com/[pagename]`, not `www.example.com/[pagename]`. Don't forget to escape the dots. Use `preg_quote()`.

Comment: @alexia: Was my answer satisfactory? If yes, please accept the answer so that everyone knows that you no longer require an answer. If not, can you tell us what more you need?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[xyz]` with `(.+)` in the second list and you have a regular expression you can use to match and extract the values from the first list. You will also need to escape characters like `.` in the rest of the line so that they don't get interpreted as special characters.

To make the replacement, use:

```
preg_replace('/\[[^]]++\]/', '(.+)', $target)
```

where `++` is a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Comment: hi, thank you!  could u please paste the regex code needed to do that replace?

Comment: @Lukman: the first closing square bracket is interpreted as a literal character because of its position right after `[^`. You could escape it if you want, though that is not necessary.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I'd probably make the `[^]]+` part possessive: `[^]]++`. That prevents needless backtracking in case the target string doesn't contain a closing square bracket.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Also I'd opt for `.+` instead of `.*` since empty pagenames are most likely not to be considered valid.